# Make Mongodb/pymongo query start executing immediately instead of waiting for the first iteration

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

```python
coll = MongoClient(uri)[database][collection]
cursor = coll.find(query, sort=sort) # I want the query to start executing here!
# It doesnt matter to my application if we're stuck here for a couple seconds
# ...
doc = next(cursor) # this must not be slow!
```

Note: I dont want to fetch *all* documents right away, just get the first document/batch of documents to avoid the lazy loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an **internal** [_refresh](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/568a3b1294711cbeeb7bff36718d981e4ad103e2/pymongo/cursor.py#L1128) method of the cursor to fetch first batch of the documents to the internal cache.

For the testing script:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import ssl
from datetime import datetime
import time

connection_string = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
print("start", datetime.now())
client = MongoClient(connection_string, ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
print("after connect", datetime.now())

db = client['test']
collection = db['companies']

documents = collection.find({}).limit(3)
print("after find", datetime.now())

documents._refresh() # <== THIS

print("after refresh", datetime.now())

time.sleep(2)
for document in documents:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("next document", datetime.now())
    print(document['_id'])

# Print the fetched document
print("end", datetime.now())
```

The screenshot below shows mongodb profiler with the timestamp of the query reaching the db on _refresh:
[image]

---

Disclaimer: use internal methods with care, and **always** cover with tests. They might change without a notice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could so it; set up a class which gets the first item in the cursor. Then use a generator to yield the first item then the remaining items in a cursor:

```
class MyCursor:
    def __init__(self, query: dict, sort: list):
        self.cursor = coll.find(query, sort=sort)
        self.first_item = next(self.cursor)
        print(self.first_item)

    def find(self):
        yield self.first_item
        yield from self.cursor
```

In a worked example with some random data:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, ASCENDING
import random
import string
import time

client = MongoClient()
db = client["mydatabase"]
coll = db["mycollection"]

coll.insert_many([
    {
        "age": random.randint(0, 100),
        "email": ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=8)) + "@example.com",
    }
    for _ in range(100000)
])


class MyCursor:
    def __init__(self, query: dict, sort: list):
        self.cursor = coll.find(query, sort=sort)
        self.first_item = next(self.cursor)
        print(f"Here's the first record to show we return it. Remove this line of code when happy: {self.first_item}")

    def find(self):
        yield self.first_item
        yield from self.cursor


query = {'age': {'$gte': 60}}
sort = [('email', ASCENDING)]
start_time = time.time()
my_cursor = MyCursor(query, sort)
print(f'Initial setup: {(time.time() - start_time) * 1000} milliseconds.')
start_time = time.time()
for index, doc in enumerate(my_cursor.find()):
    print(f'Document {index}: {(time.time() - start_time) * 1000} milliseconds.: {doc}')
    start_time = time.time()
    if index >= 2:
        break
```

prints:

```
Here's the first record to show we return it. Remove this line of code when happy: {'_id': ObjectId('65745a45c4e22463bfbfbb7b'), 'age': 96, 'email': 'aaaavqmb@example.com'}
Initial setup: 90.20113945007324 milliseconds.
Document 0: 0.0 milliseconds.: {'_id': ObjectId('65745a45c4e22463bfbfbb7b'), 'age': 96, 'email': 'aaaavqmb@example.com'}
Document 1: 0.0 milliseconds.: {'_id': ObjectId('65745a45c4e22463bfc0a9e2'), 'age': 67, 'email': 'aaagcpyh@example.com'}
Document 2: 0.0 milliseconds.: {'_id': ObjectId('65745a45c4e22463bfc002fc'), 'age': 83, 'email': 'aaaydoxt@example.com'}
```

Comment: Also maybe it goes without saying but I'll say it anyway, if you have indexes on your query / sort fields the find should return without any noticable delay.

Comment:  I was thinking something like that would work, but it is a little more complicated than what I’d like… I will accept this if nobody has a better response…